# Yii router rule to redirect a keyword to an action's $_GET Parametric

Tags: yii, yii-url-manager, yii-routing

In Yii, is it possible to use the router rule to "translate" a keyword in a URL to a certain action's $_GET Parametric?

What I want, is to let this URL:

`http://example.com/MyModule/MyController/index/foo`

to point to:

`http://example.com?r=MyModule/MyController/index&id=12`

where `foo` points to `12`.

And, since I am using "path" urlFormat, and are using other url rules to hide `index` and `id=`, the URL above should eventually point to:

`http://example.com/MyModule/MyController/12`

Is this possibe by setting rules in the config file for urlManager component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action should accept a parameter `$id`:

```
public function actionView($id) {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
```

What you need to do, is to modify the loadModel function in the same controller:

```
/**
 * @param integer or string the ID or slug of the model to be loaded
 */
public function loadModel($id) {

    if(is_numeric($id)) {
        $model = Page::model()->findByPk($id);
    } else {
        $model = Page::model()->find('slug=:slug', array(':slug' => $id));
    }

    if($model === null)
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');

    if($model->hasAttribute('isDeleted') && $model->isDeleted)
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page has been deleted for reasons of moderation.');

    // Not published, do not display
    if($model->hasAttribute('isPublished') && !$model->isPublished)
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page is not published.');

    return $model;
}
```

Then, you will need to modify the urlManager rules to accept a string, instead of just an ID:

Remove `:\d+` in the default rule below:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
```

It should be like this:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id>' => '<controller>/view',
```

One more thing to note, if you are going this path, make sure slug is unique in your database, and you should also enforce the validation rule in the model:

```
    array('slug', 'unique'),
```